# Testing my own stack class

Tags: c#, nunit

Im creating a very simple stack class to implement my learnings on TDD. I have created a test that will create a stack and check the length of it.

This is my test class:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    class StackTests
    {

        [Test]
        public void CreateStack()
        {
            Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>(5);
            Assert.AreEqual(5, stack.Size());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my actual stack class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Stack
{
   public class Stack <T>
    {
        #region Members
        private T[] stackArray;
        private int maxLength;
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public int Size { get; private set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public Stack(int Length)
        {
            maxLength = Length;
            stackArray = new T[Length];
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that im using the System.Collection.Generic framework here when creating the stack in my test case, but I want to use the class that I created, but visual studio can´t seem to find that.

Answer (score 1):

First read and learn about [namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces) and [usings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) in C#. You will need that a lot in the future.

Secondly:

1. Don't use the same names for custom created classes. You can easily change `Stack` to `MyStack` or `CustomStack` and that should be easier for VS to handle it automatically.
2. To fix this code the shorter way (but **wrong** way) change: `using System.Collections.Generic;` in `StackTest` class to `using Stack;`

Comment: Will do, thx alot for the resources!